# Android Camera returns image as Portrait, getting it as landscape?

Tags: java, android, android-camera

```
 Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, MyFileContentProvider.CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_RESULT);
```

This is how I call camera within my application, and as I require good quality output, I am using a `contentProvider` in between.

```
Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(out.getAbsolutePath());

        ImageView im1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.camTemp);
        im1.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
```

and `onActivityResult()` , this is how I display the taken image.

And in between, this is the code for the `contentProvider` class.

```
public class MyFileContentProvider extends ContentProvider {
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse
        ("content://obx.com.futurister/");
private static final HashMap<String, String> MIME_TYPES =
        new HashMap<String, String>();

static {
    MIME_TYPES.put(".jpg", "image/jpeg");
    MIME_TYPES.put(".jpeg", "image/jpeg");
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    // Implement this to handle requests to delete one or more rows.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    String path = uri.toString();

    for (String extension : MIME_TYPES.keySet()) {
        if (path.endsWith(extension)) {
            return (MIME_TYPES.get(extension));
        }
    }
    return (null);
}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    // TODO: Implement this to handle requests to insert a new row.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    try {
        File mFile = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), "newImage.jpg");
        if(!mFile.exists()) {
            mFile.createNewFile();
        }
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(CONTENT_URI, null);
        return (true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

}

@Override
public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode)
        throws FileNotFoundException {

    File f = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), "newImage.jpg");
    if (f.exists()) {
        return (ParcelFileDescriptor.open(f,
                ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_WRITE));
    }
    throw new FileNotFoundException(uri.getPath());
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                    String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    // TODO: Implement this to handle query requests from clients.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
                  String[] selectionArgs) {
    // TODO: Implement this to handle requests to update one or more rows.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
```

}

Now, the **problem** is , the image I finally obtain in the `ImageView` is `portrait`, how to obtain it as `landscape` by default ?

Comment: Generally speaking, you have no control over the camera app that produces the image. But it is strange that the result is portrait. Which device did you try?

Comment: Google nexus 5  Android 5.1

Comment: Is your activity in landscape when it starts the intent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily rotate the portrait image and get a landscape one!

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(90);
Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap , 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```